# Reverse order of number in scanner object returning a string (java)

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner, reverse

I have this major head wrecker of a assignment and I am really lost of how to go at it. The assignment is as follows:

Write a recursive method in Java public static String reverse(Scanner scan), the scanner object contains numbers and the numbers are supposed to be returned in reverse order as a string. And here's the tricky part, you're not allowed to use arrays, lists or string it's only suppose to declare one single variable.

The input of reverse(new Scanner("20 33 40") for example should return:
" 40 33 20".

I would know how to go at it if it wasn't because of the restraints. I really don't know how I am suppose to solve this. I'm pretty new at programming and I know some of you are against helping out with assignments, I would just appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I guess a stringbuilder isn't allowed as well?

Comment: Please note: it is not  that "some of us" are against helping with assignments. Point is: this site has certain policies that make up good questions; and homework help is simply not one of the good categories to go for ...

Answer (score 1):

**First possibility use String**

You can use directly the `String` as your data structure. Adding **at the beginning instead of at the end** when you read a new number.

Basically with a code like:

```
String str = "";
while (yourcondition) {
    str = scanner.nextInt() + " " + str;
}
return str;
```

**Second possibility use StringBuffer or StringBuilder**

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while (yourcondition) {
    str.insert(0, " ").insert(0, scanner.nextInt());
}
return str.toString();
```

**Third possibility use recursion:**

```
public String read(String str, Scanner scanner) {
    if (testExitCondition) {
        return str;
    }
    return scanner.nextInt() + " " + str;
}

// Called with System.out.println(read("", scanner));
```

**Note**

The first solution use String creating many instances of String, but having only one reference to it.

The second solution use existing classes that internally uses arrays to operate on strings.

The third leave to the JVM the reference to the created String, so no explicit reference to the string is present in the code. This is the only that don't have explicit variable declarations (only in the signature of method, not outside).

Comment: **you're not allowed to use arrays, lists or string**

Comment: It's also `"only suppose to declare one single variable."`, but I think the `StringBuilder` method would work if you simply inlined the `nextInt()` call.

Comment: I removed references to int declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanner.hasNext()` with a `while` loop. Use `StringBuilder` to collect prepaired data.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("12 52 10");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        builder.insert(0, scanner.next()).insert(0, " ");
    }
    builder.replace(0, 1, "");
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your limit , you get the result then output the string in reverse order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("20 33 40");
    System.err.println(scan(scanner));
}

public static String scan(Scanner scanner) {
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String next = scanner.next();
        String result = scan(scanner);
        return result.isEmpty() ? next : result + " " + next;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I think the method is required to *return* the values, not simply print them out.

Comment: I modify this to provide return value

Answer (score 0):

Writing recursive methods is a must-learn for each programming school. The technique is always the same:

1. Check whether the end condition has been reached and return the *initial value* (in math we speak of a *neutral element*).
2. Split some part of the input, call the recursive method with the remainig input, then assemble the result of that call with the previously split part.

According to that common algorithm, you have to implement your method this way:

```
public static String reverse(Scanner scan) {
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) { // check whether to continue or not
        int number = scan.nextInt(); // split part
        return reverse(scan) + " " + number; // assemble this part and the rest
    } else {
        return ""; // return an initial or base value (the neutral element)
    }
}
```

The call to `scan.nextInt()` must be done before calling the recursion, as otherwise the next number would not have split.

Comment: Very simple solution...thanks for bringing clarity to this!

Answer (score 0):

You only wanted pointers...

You must write a recursive function `String reverse(Scanner scanner)` that returns the numbers in reverse order. The point of this assignment would be to get you to grok recursion, which can be like thinking backwards.

You get passed a Scanner in the first run of your `reverse()` function with the following contents:

```
"20 33 40"
```

So, read an integer from your Scanner:

```
int value = scanner.readInt();
```

Your field `value` would contain the integer 20 and the scanner object would now seem to contain just this:

```
"33 40"
```

So, assuming that you had a reverse function that would output " 40 33" then you could just paste `value` in behind it and get " 40 33 20".

Recursion is pretending that your function already does what it should do and calling yourself with smaller versions of your input until you get to the trivial version. Your first call is with "20 33 40", the second call with "33 40", the third call "40" and the last with "".

The last call where you get passed in "" is easy. You just check for that and return "".

The other calls are not that hard either. You just read an int, and paste it together with the output from the recursive call to `reverse`.